Both pavucontrol and pwvucontrol throw segfault errors post system update
Still pretty new to arch but I ran a full system update this morning (sudo pacman -Syu and yay -Syu), and since, both pwvucontrol and pavucontrol just return the following output when run (program name and memory address aside):
MESA-INTEL: warning: ../mesa-24.2.2/src/intel/vulkan/anv_formats.c:763: FINISHME: support YUV colorspace with DRM format modifiers
MESA-INTEL: warning: ../mesa-24.2.2/src/intel/vulkan/anv_formats.c:794: FINISHME: support more multi-planar formats with DRM modifiers
[1]    21948 segmentation fault (core dumped)  pwvucontrol

I'm running pipewire with wireplumber, and both seem to be working fine, both from my being able to use them as normal, and via checking theirsystemctl status. Not sure if the two lines preceeding the segfault are important, but I did my best to update my graphics stuff to see if they were the culprit here (mesa and vulkan-intel), but no dice there. Notably, yay was broken this morning (can't recall why), and I reinstalled it via https://aur.archlinux.org/yay.git, which might be relevant. Running hyprland via wayland.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, as while things are functional, I don't know how to change the bluetooth codec without pwvucontrol, and my headset is defaulting to SBC, which is incredibly grainy.

Looks like there's a bug with vulkan & GTK4 apps, possibly specific to wayland (1).
Setting the environment variable GDK_DISABLE=vulkan to disable use of the vulkan renderer for GTK apps is the current workaround. (You can test on the command line by running GDK_DISABLE=vulkan pavucontrol.)
